# Show that it is an equivalence class

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

1. Let $A\neq \emptyset \neq B$ sets and $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a map. We define the fllowing relation: $$a\sim a' \Leftrightarrow f(a)=f(a')$$

   - Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.
   - Show that $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ an equivalence class in respect of $\sim$ for all $b\in \text{Im}(f)$.
2. We define on $(\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\})\times \mathbb{N}$ a relation as follows: $$(a,b)\sim (c,d)\Leftrightarrow ad=bc$$ Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

$$$$

I have done the following for question 2:

i) Reflexiv: $(a, b) \sim (a, b) \Leftrightarrow ab = ab$

ii) Symmetry: $(a, b) \sim (c, d) \Leftrightarrow ad = bc$ and $(c, d) \sim (a, b) \Leftrightarrow  cb = da$

then $ad = bc \Rightarrow cb = da$.

iii) Transitiv:  $(a, b)\sim (c, d) \Leftrightarrow ad = bc$, $(c, d) \sim (e, f) \Leftrightarrow cf = de$ and $(a, b) \sim (e, f) \Leftrightarrow af = be$

then $((ad = bc) \wedge (cf = de))\Rightarrow af = be$.

Could you give me a hint about the question  and especially for the second bullet?

Comment: Are you aware that in ii), you used commutativity of multiplication in $\Bbb Z$ (in fact, you implicitly used it in i) as well)? Are you aware that in iii) you used cancellability of non-zero factors in $\Bbb Z$? - Otherwise it seems that you merely *translated* the equivalence conditions. -- For part 1, apply the definitions

Comment: So is it wrong what I have done at question 2? @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 1):

To prove your second bullet point, you must show two things:

1. If $a,a' \in f^{-1}(b)$, then $a \sim a'$.
2. If $a \in f^{-1}(b)$ and $a' \notin f^{-1}(b)$, then $a\not\sim a'$.

Both are straightforward applications of the definition of $\sim$.

What you did in answering question 2 is essentially right. 
It's just that it is not conveniently spelled.
So reflexivity would be proven as
$$(a,b) \sim (a,b) \Leftrightarrow ab=ba,$$
which is true, since the product is commutative in $\mathbb Z$.
For symmetry, if $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$, then, by definition, $ad=bc$;
again, by commutativity, it follows that $cb=da$, whence $(c,d)\sim(a,b)$.
To prove transitivity, if $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ and $(c,d)\sim(e,f)$, then
$$ad=bc \quad\text{ and }\quad cf=de$$
and we want to prove that $(a,b)\sim(e,f)$, that is, $af=be$.
Now, by cancellation, $af=be$ iff $acf=bce$ iff $ade=bce$ (because $cf=de$) iff $e=e$ (because $ad=bc$), which is true, and therefore, $af=be$ and the relation is transitive.